# Finnish metal vs Swedish metal

Tags: metal

Is one of the biggest ways in which Swedish metal bands approach there music differently than there Nordic cousins the way they use keyboards.

I get the idea that the Swedes abhor keyboards and prefer the metal to be guitar-centric where the Fins are happy to use keys to add atmosphere.

Is this a regional variance of the style or do I have my wires crossed?

Comment: May be better fit for music fans.

Comment: Always good to have a fine  finnish on your metal.  Donuts should be sweetish.

Comment: The swedes abhor keyboards? How about the first albums by Pain of Salvation? How about all the wonderful Progressive Metal coming from Sweden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not particularly true whatsoever. Many Swedish bands, especially the progressive ones like Opeth and Pain of Salvation use keyboards extensively. This is actually more of a genre question as opposed to a regional question. For example, atmospheric black metal bands are very comfortable with using keyboards, whereas traditional death metal bands tend to shy away from them. It doesn't really have anything to do with which Scandinavian country the band is from.